# Integrating Surround Query Parser

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine

I want to Run surround query .

1. Downloading from
   http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/JKL/Downloadlucenesurround241jar.htm
2. Moved the lucene-surround-2.4.1.jar  to
   /apache-solr-3.1.0/example/lib
3. Edit  the solrconfig.xml with 
   `<queryParser name="SurroundQParser"
   class="org.apache.lucene.queryParser.surround.parser.QueryParser"/>`
4. Restart Solr

Got this error :

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error Instantiating QParserPlugin, org.apache.lucene.queryParser.surround.parser.QueryParser is not a org.apache.solr.search.QParserPlugin
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:425)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Never get JARs from java2s.com, it's just a website with code samples, not the official source of any JARs. In this case, the surround query parser is part of Lucene contrib, which is included in the [official Lucene distribution](http://apache.xmundo.com.ar//lucene/java/3.4.0/).
2. Support for the surround parser in Solr was only [recently added](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2703): you'll have to get a recent [nightly build for Solr 4.0](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NightlyBuilds).
3. See the patch for an example of installing the surround query parser.